# How to create NSDictionary with one key for multiple values?

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

What I know of creating NSDictionary object thus far is that each key may only have one value.

I have two keys, 'door' and 'windows', but a number of values for each - let's say five each which are all strings also. To create a dictionary out of this, do I just have to repeat the key for every value, such as `@{@"door" : @"hinge", @"door" : @"knob", @"door" : @"panel"}` or is there a better way to do this?

I want to ultimately be able to associate a number of values which will all also be strings to test if they 'match' one of these two keys via the isEqual: method. But I feel like there is a better way than repeating the key string? Can I create the key one time only and then associate multiple values with it?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What about `NSDictionary` with `NSString` keys, and `NSArray` values?`@{@"door":@[@"hinge", @"panel", @"knob"], @"window":@[@"window1, @"window2"]}`?

Comment: Map the key to a list of values, instead of a single value. `"door"` --> `["hinge", "knob", etc...]`

Comment: I'm fairly sure that you need a different container for what you are doing. An NSDictionary is not a 1 key => many objects kind of container. Perhaps you need a top level NSDictionary with each key leading to an NSArray or NSSet?

Comment: awesome, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `NSDictionary` associates one key with one object. If you want to use it, you'll need to combine your multiple values into a single object. The simplest way to do this is to put the values into another collection, most likely `NSArray` or `NSSet`.

For your example, your literal should look like this:

`@{ @"door": @[ @"hinge", @"knob", @"panel" ] }`

You could create a new type of collection (or extend/subclass `NSDictionary`), but I would first figure out what your interface needs to look like. Unfortunately, you would not be able to use a literal in the format of your first post. That forces the data into an `NSDictionary` and the first key/value pair overrides any further pairs with the same key.